# How do I show programming keywords differently?

Tags: fonts

Slack the software program, like this website has a very neat feature. When I type backticks like so: `` I am able to write any programmer word in it. Like: `someFunction()`.

How do I do this in LaTeX? I want a similar effect in the output pdf.

I am pretty sure the question is already answered, but I can't think of the right search terms to find it. The scavenger hunt for search terms is real.

Comment: Are you wanting the word to appear differently when you're editing the source code, or when you're looking at the output pdf?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm writing a thesis and I want to have a similar style like the backticks give me on StackExchange. I want to recreate that effect in LaTeX. Creating an effect in LaTeX seems very much like a LaTeX related question.

Comment: I want it to appear differently in the output pdf. My apologies for not being clear.

Comment: Like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19004/how-to-format-an-inline-source-code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. TeX-special characters, such as `_` and `&`, may occur between pairs of backtick characters. *Addendum* to incorporate a follow-up comment by the OP: Care needs to be taken in order not to mis-interpret consecutive backtick characters -- those are generally used in TeX and LaTeX documents to initiate some instance of quoted material!

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function backticks2tt ( s )
  return ( s:gsub ( "`(..-)`" , "\\texttt{\\detokenize{%1}}" ) )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
  "process_input_buffer", backticks2tt, "backticks2tt" )}}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
aa `someFunction()` bb `some_other_Function()` cc
\end{document}
```

---

A comment on the type of pattern matching that's performed by the Lua function `backticks2tt` seems indicated. The pattern

```
`(..-)`
```

is the "non-greedy" way of specifying the pattern "all instances of **one or more characters** that are encased by backtick characters". To specify a "greedy" pattern match of "one or more characters" in Lua, one would type

```
`.+`
```

However, a greedy pattern match wouldn't be appropriate here, as it would end up grabbing the entire string

```
someFunction()` bb `some_other_Function()
```

in the MWE shown above and changing it to

```
\texttt{\detokenize someFunction()` bb `some_other_Function()}
```

Clearly, that's not right, and that's why it's necessary to specify non-greedy pattern matching.

Comment: Wait... it's actually possible to do it with *actual* backticks? That is so cool! I never saw lua code but it looks quite readable :)

Comment: @MelvinRoest - This solution works as a preprocessor of sorts: By assigning the `backticks2tt` function to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, the function's work is performed *before* "ordinary LaTeX" even starts its usual processing. "Ordinary LaTeX" never actually gets to see and act on `{backtick}some_Function(){backtick}`; it only gets to see `\texttt{\detokenize{some_Function()}}`.

Comment: @MelvinRoest - Lua's string manipulation functions are very powerful. The `string.gsub` function does pattern matching and substitution. The pattern `.-` means "any string of 0 or more characters", non-greedy; to get a greedy pattern match -- which wouldn't be correct for the present application! -- one would need to write `.*`. Encasing the matched pattern in parentheses, like `(.-)`, lets it be referenced as `%1` in the second part of `gsub`.

Comment: I do have on issue with this which is: how do I type \`\`some quote''? The `` gets preprocessed.

Comment: Ah found a change that I could make. I read some links on lualatex and the - quantifier of regular expressions in general. And then I realized that one way to force a minimum of one character, non-greedy matching is to add an additional `.`. So it becomes: `"\`(..-)\`" ` as opposed to `"\`(.-)\`" `

Comment: @MelvinRoest - Indeed, my answer failed to consider the rather important case of quoted material, i.e., of strings being encased in pairs of back-quote and forward-quote glyphs. You found the perfect treatment! I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering how would you guard against the `some sentence in a single quote' case?

Comment: Ah, I can use `\lq` and `\rq`

Comment: The following question helps to redefine the `\lq` and `\rq` to one command:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113327/how-to-do-single-quotes-in-latex-suite

Comment: @MelvinRoest - A single sentence (or sentence clause) enclosed in single back- and forward quotes is no problem at all. Recall that the search pattern is for `<single backquote>...<single backquote>`. I guess if there's more than one clause on a line that's delimited by backquotes and forward quotes, it would be time to switch to a different quoting system.

Comment: A way to improve the functionality is to use: https://repl.it I am learning a humble thing or two about writing Lua :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mico's answer I got a bit more serious. For some reason, I still experienced some issues. So I decided to learn some Lua through some articles and testing it on [Repl.it](http://repl.it). The website allows me to test and print things quickly.

On [Repl.it](http://repl.it) I iterated on what I wanted until I came to my final design and tested the following code:

```
function replaceBacktick(input)
  local backtickPattern = "`(..-)`"
  local quotePattern = "`(..-)'"
  isQuoteMatch = input:find(quotePattern)
  if isQuoteMatch == nil then
    print("this is not a quote")
    print( input:gsub(backtickPattern, "\\texttt{" .. input .. "}") )
  else
    print("this is a quote")
  end
end


replaceBacktick( "``the number of correctly identified instances divided by the total number of instances \cite{leong2016} '') and 2.53\% (sensitivity which``")
replaceBacktick("`SomeReactComponent`")
```

I started working from Mico his answer, because working from my tested [Repl.it](http://repl.it) code resulted in errors and also was a lot more verbose. Still, it helped since I learned how to write if-statements and functions, I didn't know the syntax before.

I made a huge assumption that not triggering the return statement in the if-statement would be fine and would leave text in LaTeX as is (it apparently is). Printing for debugging purposes in LaTeX, even after reading some articles, is a mystery to me.

Anyways, this is the final code that works for me and ignores quotes, even single quotes!

```
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function backticks2tt ( input )
    local isQuoteMatch = input:find("`(..-)'")
    if isQuoteMatch == nil then
        return ( input:gsub ( "`(..-)`" , "\\inlinecode{\\detokenize{%1}}" ) )
    end
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
  "process_input_buffer", backticks2tt, "backticks2tt" )}}
```