# Single quotes types in Latex

Tags: quoting, quotation

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113327/how-to-do-single-quotes-in-latex-suite) question. There are two single quotes I found ` and '. The first goes diagonally and the second perpendicular. Which one is the right one to use in general and in Latex?

Answer (score 3):

`` ` `` is used to make a left quote (in English typesetting tradition) and `'` makes a right quote, so `` `foo' `` typesets as ‘foo’

`'` is also used as the apostrophe as in `foo's`  typesetting as foo’s

Use two left quotes ``` `` ``` to typeset an opening double quote and two `''` to typeset a closing double quote. Never use the ASCII double quote character `"` as a quote character (it has other uses in TeX)

Comment: Related to that: I recommend that all users pre-screen their *.tex files, either using a plain-text editor or `grep`, to find `"` and substitute (if appropriate) with something else.

Comment: @rallg hmm please don't screen any of my tex files:-)  `"` is the tex notation for a hexidecimal number....

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, what is the right way for using Possessive S (model's or model`s)?

Comment: I would always use `'` (tex will typeset them the same way anyway as will most word processing software) `'` is the classic ascii character and is on the keyboard in most layouts the typeset left and right quotes are Unicode U+2018 and U+2109 but harder to type

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know about `"` as hex (also possibly babel shortcuts). In fact, I asked about this several months ago, and you replied! But that is why I said `if appropriate` since it is context-dependent. That `tlig` substitution (left curly double quotes) may be hard to see on-screen in PDF, but is conspicuous in paper print. Understand that my own application, being fiction, uses a lot of dialogue. My unpublished doc class defines a macro `\uni{code}` that uses `"`, but after that, I screen for `"`.

Comment: @rallg you clearly need less fiction and more hexadecimal math in your life:-) actually if you stick to conventional novel text I would expect that you could fairly easily make `"foo"` work as the logic to auto replace that by "smart quotes" is fairly simple in that case as shown by the fact that word processors (and even simple markdown websites) manage it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually, I use code to flag each instance of `"` in document body, then write a log message with the count (if not zero). After `\uni` uses `"` I make it an active character, which increments a counter each time `"` is used. Message in log file if not zero at end of document. But I do not use babel shortcuts, which would complicate things. In any case, the code does not alter things, it merely sends a message. User decides what to do, if anything. Also: `"` is removed from `tlig`.